# Is it possible to inject a number into excel at every 1 minute interval using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Currently, I have a code that updates an excel sheet every 5 seconds. It will print

0 400 800 800 800

1 400 800 800 800

2 400 800 800 800

What I am trying to figure out is how do I add in a random number into that list at every 1min interval, for example,

0 400 800 800 800

1 **425** 800 800 800

2 400 800 800 800

The code shown here is the current code I am having and was wondering if anyone can help me out here, thanks so much :).

```
import csv
import random
import time

x_value = 0
total_1 = 400 #voltage
total_2 = 800 #current(1)
total_3 = 800 #current(2)
total_4 = 800 #current(3)

fieldnames = ["Timestamp", "Voltage", "[L1] Current(1)", "[L1] Current(2)", "[L1] Current(3)"]

with open('test 4.0.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    
while True:
    with open('test 4.0.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
        
        info = {
            "Timestamp": x_value,
            "Voltage": total_1,
            "[L1] Current(1)": total_2,
            "[L1] Current(2)": total_3,
            "[L1] Current(3)": total_4
            }
        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, total_1, total_2, total_3, total_4)
        
        x_value += 1

    time.sleep(5) #controls the speed of the loop eg. 1 = 1sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by adding a simple flag to indicate if the voltage value should be randomized.

Before your loop, you may initialize a flag by

```
...
total_4 = 800 #current(3)
randomVoltageFlag = False # new flag
...
```

Then in your loop, check if the flag is true and assign the value accordingly

```
While True:
    ...
    info = {
       ...
       "Voltage": random.randrange(200,500) if randomVoltageFlag else total_1,
       ...
```

Lastly, at the end of your loop, you can switch the flag to flip it for the next iteration

```
randomVoltageFlag = not randomVoltageFlag
```

The full modified code should now be

```
import csv
import random
import time

x_value = 0
total_1 = 400 #voltage
total_2 = 800 #current(1)
total_3 = 800 #current(2)
total_4 = 800 #current(3)
randomVoltageFlag = False # new flag

fieldnames = ["Timestamp", "Voltage", "[L1] Current(1)", "[L1] Current(2)", "[L1] Current(3)"]

with open('test 4.0.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    
while True:
    with open('test 4.0.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
        
        info = {
            "Timestamp": x_value,
            "Voltage": random.randrange(200,500) if randomVoltageFlag else total_1,
            "[L1] Current(1)": total_2,
            "[L1] Current(2)": total_3,
            "[L1] Current(3)": total_4
            }
        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, total_1, total_2, total_3, total_4)
        
        x_value += 1
        randomVoltageFlag = not randomVoltageFlag
    time.sleep(5) #controls the speed of the loop eg. 1 = 1sec
```

Notes, this is just an example for you. ***It can be further optimized by replacing the flag with your x_value by utilizing the `%` mod operator,*** but I will leave that part for you to try.

Comment: Glad it helps! It would be better if you can accept this answer in order to close the question as answered too.

Comment: Hi burningalc, one more question, if i want to delay the iteration, like instead of TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE, change it to FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: If you wanna do it, you should be first trying to replace the flag with your `x_value` by using `%`. Then you can adjust the divider value to achieve that, such as `x_value + 1 % 3` for your case.

Comment: Im sorry, i do not understand what you mean by replacing the flag with my x_value by using %.

Comment: Try to replace the line `"Voltage": random.randrange(200,500) if randomVoltageFlag else total_1` with `"Voltage": random.randrange(200,500) if x_value + 1 % 3 == 0 else total_1`